# What is the fastest way to write dataframe to mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I try to use

```
pd.DataFrame.to_sql(tablename, engine_ts, index=False, if_exists='append',chunksize=10000)
```

to write to `mysql`, and the write performance is about `15,000` rows per second, while my data exceeds `10 million` rows. I heard that transaction processing and batch writing can greatly increase the speed, but I did not find the correct method.

Comment: If you change that to write 1 row per transaction, than you will see that it will become slower ...

Comment: 10 million rows of data, just one-time write, half an hour to complete, it is acceptable